# how do i reset or uninstall wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, networking

My ISP WiFi is not connecting anymore.  Time Warner asked if i could have Ubuntu talk me through uninstall & reinstall.... finding a usa 800 phone number was the first problem.
Now i am spending all my time searching for help. 
The error message I get every time now when wifi is trying to connect is as follows: "Wireless Authentification Required.  Passwords or encryption keys are required to access wireless network. (Password is already there in the box) (I click on connect and it tries but never authenticates , thus never connects)

Please if there is anyone out there who can assist I would tremendously appreciate it.
I am a user and need very simple instructions.
Thank You
William
Los Angeles

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/469575/repeated-authentication-required-for-wifi

Answer (score 0):

`sudo service network-manager restart`

This should reset the network-manager, thus resetting your WiFi. Hope this helps!